# How have British English U and non-U speech changed between the 1950s and now?

Tags: vocabulary

How have British English [U and non-U speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English) changed between the 1950s and the present day?

Comment: A wee bit broad mate!

Comment: "Many, if not most, of the differences however are still very much current — and therefore perfectly usable — as class-indicators." is in the last paragraph of wikipedia article. It references a book.

Comment: is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia page on RP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) lists some of the changes. One of the changes which sticks out when one hears it nowadays is the *s* sound in words like *tissue* (/ˈtɪsjuː/) and *suit* (/ˈsjuːt/).